# Proof closed walk with no repeated edges must contain simple cycle

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

A closed walk in a graph $G(V,E)$ is any sequence of vertices $(v_0, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{k-1}, v_0)$ where $v_0, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{k-1} \in V$ and there is an edge between every consecutive pair of vertices i.e. $\forall i \in [k], (v_{i-1}, v_{i}) \in E$ and $(v_{k-1}, v_0) \in E$. Note that some of the vertices in the walk can be repeated. If no vertex is repeated (except the first and last which are both $v_0$ here) it is a simple cycle. Show that if the graph $G$ has a closed walk with no edges on it being repeated, then $G$ also has a simple cycle.

Comment: Is your graph simple (i.e., no loops and no parallel edges)? Is your graph directed (i.e. a digraph)?

Comment: my graph is undirected and simple @Moritz

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $A$ be the set of vertices that occur at least twice on the walk; $A\ne\varnothing$, since $v_0\in A$. For each $v\in A$ let $k(V)$ be the index of $v$’s *second* appearance on the walk. There is a unique $u\in A$ such that $k(u)\le k(v)$ for each $v\in A$. Show that the walk contains a simple cycle through $u$.